# How to Put request with json payload with rest assured

Tags: rest-assured

I want to load the JSON file in a body with rest assured but getting error 415.

Can you please help me?

code is:

```
public class Entitlement_Creation extends BaseClass {

@Test
public void JsonPayload() throws IOException
{

    Path json_data = Paths.get("test.json");
    byte[] wikiArray = Files.readAllBytes(json_data);

    String wikiString = new String(wikiArray);
    System.out.println(wikiString);   

         given()
           .contentType(ContentType.JSON)
           .accept(ContentType.JSON)

           .body(wikiString)

       .when()  
           .put()

       .then()
           .statusCode(200)
           .extract()
           .response();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

from this snippet, I can't see any information about URL of your service.
You should put your URL as an argument to put() method.

Comment: I have put the url using base class ... public class BaseClass {
 
 
    @BeforeClass
 public void setup()
 {
 
   RestAssured.authentication=RestAssured.preemptive().basic("username", "password");

   RestAssured.baseURI="https://niceltdqa03.tps.sentinelcloud.com:443/niceerpconnector/entitlement";
   
  
 }
 

}

Comment: @mielmat this should be acomment